# How to check list of dictionary values in python 2?

Tags: python-2.7

Hello I have a list of string and list of dictionary

I want to compare my list of string on the list of dictionary values.
For example:

```
# List of strings
my_list = ['john', 'james', 'joey']

# List of dictionary
results = [{name: 'john', age: 20}, {name: 'james', age: 25}]

# This is my code and its wrong.
for name in my_list:
# getting error here that said 'list indices must be integers, not unicode'
   if name is not in results['name']:

       # I want to add joey here
       new_person = {
           'name' = 'joey',
           'age' = 30
       }
       results.append(new_person)
```

Comment: Your list of dictionaries is invalid. Are you sure it's not `'name'` instead of just `name` as the key?

Comment: yes im sure.. its just an example but the real one is a response from an API

Comment: So you want to find the list of people in `my_list` who do not exist in `results` and for each of those people that donot exist, you'd like to add them to the `results` dictionary right?

Comment: yes sir @SudheeshSinganamalla, im just new on python

Comment: Are you also assured that the length of `my_list` is greater than the length of list of dictionaries?

Comment: yep.. because some response from the api will remove some of my_list if there is no value on it

Comment: If there will be 2 persons with same name in the list of dictionaries then what action should be taken. Please provide some inputs and  expected outputs combination.

Comment: before making the request in API, the code will check if there will be duplicate name and will remove it from the my_list. I will make a request my_list and sometimes the response will return some of the list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@Mark**, here I've shown 3 ways to solve the problem. Please check it and let me know if it satisfies your problem or not with some set of new inputs and expected outputs.
I'll update the code based on that.

#### First way - Using list comprehension, extend(), set()

> try it online at http://rextester.com/WEE27295.

```
# List of strings
my_list = ['john', 'james', 'joey']

# List of dictionaries
results = [{"name": 'john', "age": 20}, {"name": 'james', "age": 25}]

new_persons = [{"name": name, "age": 30} for name in set(my_list) if name not in set((person["name"] for person in results))];
results.extend(new_persons);

print(results)
```

» Output

```
[{'age': 20, 'name': 'john'}, {'age': 25, 'name': 'james'}, {'age': 30, 'name': 'joey'}]
```

#### » Second way - Using set()

> Try it online at http://rextester.com/WBAT64136.

```
# List of strings
my_list = ['john', 'james', 'joey']

# List of dictionaries
results = [{"name": 'john', "age": 20}, {"name": 'james', "age": 25}]
unique_names = set((person["name"] for person in results));

for name in my_list:
   if name not in unique_names:
       new_person = {
           'name': name,
           'age': 30
       }
       results.append(new_person);

print(results)
```

&» Output

```
[{'age': 20, 'name': 'john'}, {'age': 25, 'name': 'james'}, {'age': 30, 'name': 'joey'}]
```

#### » Third way - Using nested loops

> Try it online at http://rextester.com/DSB44497.

```
# List of strings
my_list = ['john', 'james', 'joey']

# List of dictionaries
results = [{"name": 'john', "age": 20}, {"name": 'james', "age": 25}]

for name in my_list:
 found = False;
 for person in results:
     if person["name"] == name:
          found = True

 if not found:
     new_person = {
         'name': name,
         'age': 30
     }
     results.append(new_person);

print(results)
```

» Output

```
[{'name': 'john', 'age': 20}, {'name': 'james', 'age': 25}, {'name': 'joey', 'age': 30}]
```

Comment: This is quite an expensive thing to do. You're checking the entire `results` list for each item in `my_list` and then adding the list of members accordingly.

Comment: I just modified the code, made it working.Let me find the easiest one and then I'll update it. Thanks.

Comment: your code works for me.. but it will take some time if the results will be thousands or more

Comment: **@Mark**, now, I've added one more way to do the same using the concept of `set()`. Finding other ways too. Please check it.

Comment: @RishikeshAgrawani ok sir.. i will be back for the output of your examples.. thank you

Comment: **@Mark**, no problem. Use `set()` to get a set of unique items from a list of duplicated items.. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you'll not have duplicate names in `my_list` or in the `results`. You could use `set()` to simplify any intersection operations you'd want to use:

```
# List of strings, Preferably convert this to a set
my_list = set(['john', 'james', 'joey'])

# List of dictionary
results = [{name: 'john', age: 20}, {name: 'james', age: 25}]

names_in_list = set([result['name'] for result in results])
names_to_add = names_in_list ^ my_list  # This returns the difference between the two sets

# Add each of the names to the list
for name in names_to_add:
    new_person = {
        'name': name,
        'age': 30   
    }
    results.append(new_person)
```

A simple way of doing this would be to check every item in the list of dictionaries for existence in `my_list` as follows:

```
my_list = ['john', 'james', 'joey']
names_in_list = [result['name'] for result in results]
for name in my_list:
    if name not in names_in_list:
        # Add the name to the results list
        new_person = {
            'name': name,
            'age' : 30
        }
        results.append(new_person)
```

The result is as follows:

```
[{'age': 20, 'name': 'john'},
 {'age': 25, 'name': 'james'},
 {'age': 30, 'name': 'joey'}]
```